# Which framework is best suited for full integration test?

Tags: test-automation-framework

I am a beginner to Selenium, I have started automating simple practice sites using Selenium Webdriver with java. Now I want to follow some framework for full integration testing, but I am little confused about what framework to use. I read about cucumber and junit, please help me understand the difference between these frameworks and which framework will be best suited for integrated tests?

Comment: There is no framework that is specifically "good" for integration test. It only depends on how you implement them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the scope of your project requirement, if your project demands to use bdd methodology,  use can explore cucumber-jvm, . Junit is a unit testing tool which is used to build the testautomation framework,  nd where as cucumber is bdd spec where we define scenarios in terms of business requirements